# Stack Exchange should optimize its logo on Google+

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The current [profile](https://plus.google.com/101120115153580954446/posts)'s *avatar* looks like this:

[image: Stack Exchange logo on Google+]

Zoom in and you can clearly see what's wrong with this image:

[image: Visible artifacts]

[Direct link to image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-pqEHFxof-wg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAADA/4dmRIKTUhUY/s200-c-k/photo.jpg)

I work at an advertising agency, and I always have to remind people to use .png or .gif files instead of .jpeg for logos and typographic images. This is because JPEG compression always results in visible artifacts. In a photographic image these are not that apparent. In a logo however, they tend to be distracting.

If that's not possible my advise is to use .jpg with little or no compression (high quality) to prevent the most visible artifacts like you see above (the dirty white around and between the lines of the logo).

Examples (I couldn't find a high-res version)

**.gif**

[image: Stack Exchange logo (.gif)]

**.png**

[image: Stack Exchange logo (.png)]

**.jpg** (quality: 100, some artifacts, but not distracting at smaller sizes)

[image: Stack Exchange logo (.jpg)]

Comment: It's probably just me not being a design / marketing person, but I don't see much of a difference.  What's the point?

Comment: +1 please use a PNG or a good GIF if at all possible. Those artifacts are SO ugly.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I added a close-up, can you see it now?

Comment: I'm sure it was a CHAOS hack job and not Jin's work.

Comment: @yoda I don't get it?

Comment: I'm going with Yoda here. That's not official property, just a social network. Also, because I have no clue, is it possible someone did a "import from link" and the g+ software pulled it as a jpg? I really have no clue.

Comment: Ugh, the full size profile image is also not transparent nor does it match the Google+ #FFFFFF background. Fixitfixitfixit

Comment: @jcolebrand I don't see where michielvoo indicated it was Jin's work?  Regardless of who's work it is, if this is the official representation of Stack Exchange on Google+, then SE (not Jin, but *all* of SE) should be concerned with *all* of their official representations.

Comment: @jcolebrand That said, I don't think this was Jin's work either =P

Comment: With Google+'s importance in Google search a good Google+ presence is very important for businesses as well. This underscores @casperOne's point about it being a (important) official representation of SE.

Comment: @casperOne I meant in response to his asking about what Yoda meant. I should've said "don't you think the professional designer would've ensured this was up to snuff" and I went for the shorter version. Obviously we have a SUPER EXEMPLARY MASTER OF DESIGN on staff (which should be his title or something), so that was almost obviously the work of someone else, who is not a designer.

Comment: @jcolebrand I believe the official title is "CREATOR OF ALL THAT IS BEAUTIFUL DIGITAL OR NOT".  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @jcolebrand I cannot prove that. Relevant: I don't know who Jin is.

Comment: And now we come to the root of the matter. Thank you to @michielvoo for the notification, and welcome to [meta] ... the land of terror and assholes in abundance, but of course ;-) ... we just assume everyone here knows what we know and that they all have invested two or more years of their life in the network ;-) Jin is the resident designer, and damnit if he isn't great at his task.

Comment: Why does Jin matter here? He does the design but this is an issue that should be fixed period, not one that only applies if Jin did it or one that only Jin can fix.

Comment: Because Jin is the one to design logos for the stacks, no?

Comment: @jcolebrand yeah, but someone surely has the unmolested art assets, whoever has the G+ account just needs to correctly save or upload a copy of the "good" art asset to G+.

Comment: idk, where's there a large logo like that on the stacks? I looked briefly and didn't see one...

Comment: for those who are interested, making the G+ profile image 200x200px, with a solid bgcolor yields the best result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We updated the image it should look better now.

Comment: Looks very sharp, what file format did you upload?

Comment: @michielvoo png with white bg, 200x200 px

Comment: Weird that Google+ insists that it's a [JPEG](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-pqEHFxof-wg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAc4/byRvMxf7pP0/s200-c-k/photo.jpg) in the URL (although the mime type is actually correct)